# XAML C# Resources - Como adicionar uma lista de resources Image dinamicamente baseada em uma pasta

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Estou fazendo um `FlipView` usando `MahApps.Metro.`

Eu tenho uma lista de imagens que seriam passadas para esse flipview. Funciona, mas estou fazendo elas serem adicionadas dinamicamente de uma forma que creio ser incorreta:

```
    <Image x:Key="Fdl1" Source="Resources/Layouts/1.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl2" Source="Resources/Layouts/2.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl3" Source="Resources/Layouts/3.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl4" Source="Resources/Layouts/4.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl5" Source="Resources/Layouts/5.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl6" Source="Resources/Layouts/6.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl7" Source="Resources/Layouts/7.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl8" Source="Resources/Layouts/8.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl9" Source="Resources/Layouts/9.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl10" Source="Resources/Layouts/10.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl11" Source="Resources/Layouts/11.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl12" Source="Resources/Layouts/12.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl13" Source="Resources/Layouts/13.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl14" Source="Resources/Layouts/14.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl15" Source="Resources/Layouts/15.bmp" />
    <Image x:Key="Fdl16" Source="Resources/Layouts/16.bmp" />
```

Observem a Key tendo um padrão numérico sequencial. Após isto, para acessá-los e incluir no FlipView dinamicamente no code behind, eu faço uma nova cachorrisse:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= FACTORY_IMG_TOTAL_RESOURCES; i++)
        {
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush();
            vb.Visual = (Visual)this.Resources["Fdl" + i]; // esta é a parte que 
                                                           // me escondo debaixo da mesa
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Width = 300;
            rect.Height = 188.51;
            rect.Fill = vb;
            Grid g = new Grid();
            g.Children.Add(rect);
            FpImg.Items.Add(g);
        }
```

Como vocês podem ver, se eu excluo uma das imagens já deve estourar exception por não existir. 
Eu queria tornar isto mais maleável. 
Eu imagino algo como quando adiciono uma nova imagem na pasta Resources/Layouts o `XAML` já tenha uma lista de `resources` baseada nessa pasta, então, consequentemente, esta nova imagem também estará lá. Mas não sei como criar uma lista de `resources` ou algo parecido.
E no `CodeBehind` eu queria poder criar um `foreach` para buscar todas essas imagens. Sendo uma coleção, isto deve ser bem mais fácil.

Será ótimo para o meu aprendizado, pois este mesmo problema estou tendo em alguns outros casos.

Comment: Como você percebeu esses `Resources` são estáticos, ou seja, não tem como manipulá-los, uma solução seria manipular a adição/remoção dos arquivos através de arquivos `json` ou `xml`. @robson-ribeiro-faxas

Comment: Resolvi da maneira mais tradicional, adicionei os dados no banco de dados.

Comment: Porém, o carregamento das imagens na tela de seleção era lento devido a quantidade de dados, então criei uma Thread que busca as imagens no banco e implementa o progresso de uma progressbar. Assim a execução não fica travada e o processo é carregado normalmente.

Usar json ou xml é uma possibilidade interessante também, vou incluir esta possibilidade da próxima vez que precisar carregar muitos resources.